# difference between extern declared variables and global variables

Tags: c++, c, oop, variables

I am confused on what are the benefits we get on declaring a variable with *extern* in the hxx file and then later defining it in each of the cxx files.

I understand that we do save memory here(If there are 10 source files, instead of having 10 times memory we are just allocating it one time). Other than that is their any other extensive benefit of *extern*? How is it different from a normal global variable declared in the hxx file?

What i understand *extern* does to a variable is: When declared with extern, a variable is just declared once but can be defined multiple times. Its like having separate variable for each of the source files without allocating memory again and again.

I am missing something here, It would be great to get some detailed explanations here. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> What i understand extern does to a variable is: When declared with extern, a variable is just declared once but can be defined multiple times.

No, that is incorrect.

Generally, an object or function is defined **once**, in **one** source file.

It is declared in a header file associated with that source file. That header file is included by other source files to include that declaration. The declaration makes information about the object or function known to the compiler while it is compiling the other source files. It does not define the object or function. It just gives the compiler information it needs to make use of the object or function.

(The header file should also be included in the source file it is associated with. This is so the compiler sees both the declaration and the definition in the same compilation, so it will print a warning if there is a discrepancy.)

> Its like having separate variable for each of the source files without allocating memory again and again.

No, there is one definition, so there is not a separate object for each source file. There is one object that is used (shared) by multiple source files.

Comment: +1. I understand what you explained, but maybe you missed "How is it different from a normal global variable declared in the hxx file?". Could you explain this too please.

Comment: @ShivamKumarSingh: A declaration like `extern int x;` is used in a header file. It just declares `x` and does not define it. A declaration like `int x = 4;` is used in a source file. It defines `x` (and also is a declaration). For historical reasons, a declaration like `int x;` at file scope is somewhat mixed; it can serve as a definition as well. Also for historical reasons, the effects `extern` has depend somewhat on circumstances and are complicated to explain completely. Mostly, use `extern` when just declaring and do not use it when defining.

Comment: I get it completely now. Thanks a ton!!